Is there a clean method to find line segment intersections?
How can I find the intersection coordinates of a pair of line segments where they intersect at a single point? I tried using Solve to find the intersection, but I don't know how to neatly handle cases where there is no solution or infinitely many solutions, so I'm looking for a cleaner way to do this. I'm going to apply this to around 2,000 pairs, so it would be great if it doesn't take too long to run. 
Below are examples of pairs, where only the first pair intersects at a point.
pairs = {{ConditionalExpression[1, -1 <= x <= 2], 
    ConditionalExpression[1/2 + x, 
     0 <= x <= 1]}, {ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2], 
    ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2]}, {ConditionalExpression[
     2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2], 
    ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, 
     x <= 1]}, {ConditionalExpression[-1 + x, x >= 2], 
    ConditionalExpression[x, x < 1]}};
Plot[#, {x, -3, 3}] & /@ pairs


The expected result would be to return the intersection point if there is a single intersection, and return nothing if there is no intersection or if there are infinite intersections.

What about using Line[{{0, 1/2}, {1, 3/2}}] instead of ConditionalExpression[1/2 + x, 0 <= x <= 1]? Isn't it simpler to use?

Agreed with @azerbajdzan, specifying the line segments by their endpoints is going to be much simpler to manipulate.

@azerbajdzan actually they are not always possible to express as two points for example line  1-x where x < 1.

There is an undocumented built-in to do this see.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pairs = {
   {ConditionalExpression[1, -1 <= x <= 2], 
    ConditionalExpression[1/2 + x, 0 <= x <= 1]},
   {ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2], 
    ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2]},
   {ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2], 
    ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1]},
   {ConditionalExpression[-1 + x, x >= 2], 
    ConditionalExpression[x, x < 1]}};

intersections = RegionIntersection @@@
  (pairs /. ConditionalExpression[expr_, cond_] :>
     ImplicitRegion[{y == expr, cond}, {x, y}])

(* {ImplicitRegion[y == 1 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 1/2 + x == y, {x, y}], 
 ImplicitRegion[y == 2 - 3 x && x <= 1/2, {x, y}], 
 ImplicitRegion[3 x + y == 2 && 2 x <= 1, {x, y}], EmptyRegion[2]} *)

sol = (({x, y} /. Solve[#, Reals][[1]]) & @@@ intersections) /.
   _ReplaceAll :> "Disjoint" // Quiet

(* {{1/2, 1}, {ConditionalExpression[(2 - y)/3, y >= 1/2], 
  y}, {ConditionalExpression[(2 - y)/3, y >= 1/2], y}, "Disjoint"} *)

sol2 = (# /. e_?(! FreeQ[#, ConditionalExpression] &) :> "Overlap") & /@ sol

(* {{1/2, 1}, "Overlap", "Overlap", "Disjoint"} *)

Or change "Disjoint" and "Overlap" to Nothing
EDIT: With revised pairs
pairs = {
   {ConditionalExpression[1, -1 <= x <= 2],
    ConditionalExpression[1/2 + x, 0 <= x <= 1]},
   {ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2],
    ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2]},
   {ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2],
    ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1]},
   {ConditionalExpression[-1 + x, x >= 2],
    ConditionalExpression[x, x < 1]},
   {ConditionalExpression[1, x <= -1],
    ConditionalExpression[1, x <= 1]}};

intersections = 
  RegionIntersection @@@ (pairs /. 
     ConditionalExpression[expr_, cond_] :> 
      ImplicitRegion[{y == expr, cond}, {x, y}]);

solRev = # /. {
      e_?(! FreeQ[#, Reduce] &) :> "Disjoint",
      e_?(! FreeQ[#, ToRules] &) :> "Overlap",
      e_?(! FreeQ[#, Rule] &) :> ({x, y} /. e)} & /@
   ({Reduce[#, {x, y}, Reals] // ToRules} & @@@
     intersections) // Quiet

(* {{{1/2, 1}}, "Overlap", "Overlap", "Disjoint", "Overlap"} *)


Would it possible to make it to return Overlap in this case as well {ConditionalExpression[1, x <= -1], ConditionalExpression[1, x <= 1]}?

pairs = {{ConditionalExpression[1, -1 <= x <= 2], 
    ConditionalExpression[1/2 + x, 
     0 <= x <= 1]}, {ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2], 
    ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2]}, {ConditionalExpression[
     2 - 3 x, x <= 1/2], 
    ConditionalExpression[2 - 3 x, 
     x <= 1]}, {ConditionalExpression[-1 + x, x >= 2], 
    ConditionalExpression[x, x < 1]}};

RegionIntersection @@@ (pairs /. 
   ConditionalExpression[a_, b_] :> 
    Which[b /. x -> -∞, 
     HalfLine[({x, a} /. x -> #) & /@ Join[#, # - 1] &@
       Cases[b, (x_ /; NumericQ[x])]], b /. x -> ∞, 
     HalfLine[({x, a} /. x -> #) & /@ Join[#, # + 1] &@
       Cases[b, (x_ /; NumericQ[x])]], True, 
     Line[({x, a} /. x -> #) & /@ Cases[b, (x_ /; NumericQ[x])]]])

Replace[%, Except[x_Point] -> {}, 1]


{Point[{{1/2, 1}}], HalfLine[{{1/2, 1/2}, {-(1/2), 7/2}}], 
 HalfLine[{{1/2, 1/2}, {-(1/2), 7/2}}], EmptyRegion[2]}

{Point[{{1/2, 1}}], {}, {}, {}}

Shortened version with With:
RegionIntersection @@@ (pairs /. 
   ConditionalExpression[a_, b_] :> 
    With[{case = Cases[b, (x_ /; NumericQ[x])]}, 
     Which[b /. x -> -∞, 
      HalfLine[({x, a} /. x -> #) & /@ Join[#, # - 1] &@case], 
      b /. x -> ∞, 
      HalfLine[({x, a} /. x -> #) & /@ Join[#, # + 1] &@case], True, 
      Line[({x, a} /. x -> #) & /@ case]]])

